# How can I make an object transparent in material preview mode for viewport shading?

Tags: 3d-view, transparency

I am using a material as reference for my modeling. Im therefor using 'material preview' mode as viewport shading. Is there a way to make the model transparent so i can see the reference behind it? Or is it better if i use reference planes instead in solid shading?

thank you!

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

You could enable the *In Front* option of your reference image, and also lower down its *Opacity*:

[image]

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: I not currently using a reference object. But a plane with a material. I'll switch over as its probably alot more convenient that way! thanks!